# Qonversion not adding as a package to Xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I am using Xcode 13.3 on MacOS 12.2.1.  I am trying to add the Qonversion package from Github to my Xcode project, however it keeps failing with an error saying "Received invalid response at https://github.com/qonversion/qonversion-ios-sdk (see image below).

[image]

I am trying to bring in the conversion package into my Xcode project by:

1. opening my Xcode project
2. going to file, selecting "Add Packages.."
3. Clicking on the "+" sign in bottom left corner to 'Add Swift Package Collection'
4. Pasting the URL for the GitHub package collection from the qonversion.io website (alternatively I have used the conversion.io website instructions from the Documentation -> SDK IoS to get the link)

It doesn't seem to matter how I do it, I am unable to get Xcode to accept the package.

Any ideas from anyone who may have tried importing with Xcode 13.3 ??

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the issue of the package not being added.  You have to:

1. Open the Xcode project
2. Go to file and select "Add Packages"
3. When the package window appears, do NOT select the + sign but instead copy the github URL into the search field in the top right hand corner where it says "Search or Enter Package URL"
4. If step 3 was successful, the qonversion-ios-sdk will then be displayed in the middle section of the window, whereby you then click on the package to highlight it
5. Click on the 'Add to Project" dropdown and select your project (app)
6. Click on the "Add Package" button in the bottom right hand corner
7. The package should then install, however you have to hit the new/additional "Add Package" button for the package to install.

Voila.... nothing like bad Xcode documentation or trying to follow a YouTube video that is just 1 year old (given Xcode seems to be getting updated constantly with new ways of doing things and older ways being deprecated)...